# Querying Orient DB with 'joins'

Tags: orientdb, orientdb-2.1

I've recently started looking at OrientDB coming from a relational background (Oracle RDBMS) and I'm struggling to query some data I've loaded into OrientDB.

I have 2 classes:

```
CREATE CLASS prices
CREATE PROPERTY prices.price_created_datetime DATETIME
CREATE PROPERTY prices.price_value DOUBLE

CREATE CLASS stocks
CREATE PROPERTY stocks.stock_symbol STRING
CREATE PROPERTY stocks.stock_prices LINKLIST prices
```

I'm loading some data by first running an UPSERT on the 'stocks' class, and then several times over the day adding prices:

```
UPDATE stocks ADD stock_prices = {json string of class:prices}
```

What I'd like to do is get all stocks.stock_symbol values and aggregate (using average) the prices.price_value within the last 24 hours (therefore filtering on prices.price_created_datetime).

I'm using the web based studio and I've toyed with a few different methods but I'm struggling to get the concept when most of my queries return nothing. I have OrientDB 2.1.9 running embedded in a Java application.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to write a query to do what you need

Comment: Hi @IvanMainetti let me know how you get on :)

Comment: Hi, I'm trying @LucaS' query and it seams to work for me! Eventually is it possible for you to upload a small export of the db?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I tried your case with this structure (like yours):

Class: `stocks`

Property: `stocks.stock_symbol STRING`

Property: `stocks.stock_prices LINKLIST prices`

Class: `prices`

Property: `prices.price_created_datetime DATETIME`

Property: `prices.price_value DOUBLE`

And here's the data:

[image]

[image]

To find all of stock symbols with relative prices average of the last 24 hours, I used this query:

```
select stock_symbol, $prices.averageLast24 as averagePricesLast24 from stocks 
let $prices = (select avg(price_value) as averageLast24 from (select price_value, price_created_datetime.asDatetime() as dataLast24 from prices) where eval('(sysdate() - dataLast24) / 3600000') < 24 and dataLast24 in $parent.current.stock_prices.price_created_datetime) 
unwind averagePricesLast24
```

and this is the output:

```
----+------+------------+-------------------
#   |@CLASS|stock_symbol|averagePricesLast24
----+------+------------+-------------------
0   |null  |bbb         |492345.5
1   |null  |ccc         |320167.0
----+------+------------+-------------------
```

Hope it helps

Comment: So... that doesn't seem to work, at least not with my data set. It returns a result but the aggregate is waaaaaay off.

Comment: Hi, did you execte the same query ? Could you give me an example of yout output ? or a screenshot of your classes and data ?

Comment: Hi, did you have a chance to try the query ?

Comment: Hi @LucaS - thank you very much for responding. I've managed to get my query working in the end - I didn't use LET, but I think we've technically got similar queries.

Comment: Hi @JAC2703, what's your solution ?